# How to test dependence between X and Y in annual data?

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, mixed-model, arima

This is a sample from my original data set.

I need to test whether **y** is significantly dependent on **x (y~x)**, and I am thinking about how to model that properly.

The problem is that this is annual data; each combination of destination and model can not be duplicated in a year, so [Milan; XG] can not be given twice in 2018. But there is no guarantee that each combination of model and destination is given in every year, for instance [Milan; XG] can be in 2018 but not in 2020.

Could you tell me which model would fit this issue? And how?

```
structure(list(destination = c("Milan", "MIlan", "MIlan", "London", 
"London", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Rome", "Rome", 
"Milan", "MIlan", "Brasil", "Brasil", "Brasil", "Brasil", "Paris", 
"Rome", "Rome", "Milan", "London", "London", "London", "NY", 
"NY"), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L), model = c("XG", "A", "B", "XG", "A", "XG", "B", "C", 
"D", "A", "XG", "A", "XG", "A", "D", "XG", "B", "XG", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "XG", "C", "A", "XG"), y = c(34, 134, 31, 22, 345, 
435, 45, 453, 55, 348, 89, 785, 980, 889, 567, 547, 33, 2354, 
34, 22, 452, 4524, 435, 345, 345, 534), x = c(17.6695512, 35.07829364, 
16.87201322, 14.21338109, 56.28538067, 63.20198065, 20.3278907, 
64.4963535, 22.47332875, 56.52957002, 28.58782161, 84.90258016, 
94.86348995, 90.35182737, 72.15685394, 70.8728216, 17.4077656, 
147.0243572, 17.6695512, 14.21338109, 64.42512614, 203.8202633, 
63.20198065, 56.28538067, 56.28538067, 70.02557581)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))


   destination year model    y         x
1        Milan 2018    XG   34  17.66955
2        MIlan 2018     A  134  35.07829
3        MIlan 2018     B   31  16.87201
4       London 2018    XG   22  14.21338
5       London 2018     A  345  56.28538
6        Paris 2018    XG  435  63.20198
7        Paris 2018     B   45  20.32789
8        Paris 2018     C  453  64.49635
9        Paris 2018     D   55  22.47333
10        Rome 2018     A  348  56.52957
11        Rome 2018    XG   89  28.58782
12       Milan 2019     A  785  84.90258
13       MIlan 2019    XG  980  94.86349
14      Brasil 2019     A  889  90.35183
15      Brasil 2019     D  567  72.15685
16      Brasil 2019    XG  547  70.87282
17      Brasil 2019     B   33  17.40777
18       Paris 2019    XG 2354 147.02436
19        Rome 2019     B   34  17.66955
20        Rome 2019     A   22  14.21338
21       Milan 2020     B  452  64.42513
22      London 2020     A 4524 203.82026
23      London 2020    XG  435  63.20198
24      London 2020     C  345  56.28538
25          NY 2020     A  345  56.28538
26          NY 2020    XG  534  70.02558
```